# Ruby: XmlSimple strange behavior or doing it wrong?

Tags: ruby

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmlsimple'

data = XmlSimple.xml_in("<Product><ProductId>12341234</ProductId><Title>Some text here, 11234. and here, 234. and here </Title></Product>")
puts data['Title'].is_a? Array
```

Why it's an array instead of string? O_o

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
data = XmlSimple.xml_in yourxml, { 'ForceArray' => false}
```

The options is `true` by default because normally you want nested elements be folded into hashes.